# Bokeh cursession() AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute 'store_objects'

Tags: python, python-2.7, bokeh

*NOTE from maintainers: this question concerns the obsolete first generation bokeh server, removed years ago. For modern Bokeh, see:*

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

---

---

I'm trying to set up a simple streaming bokeh example in IPython notebook, but am having some trouble with the final step.  For reference, I'm using bokeh 0.7.1 from Anaconda, on Windows 7.  In my notebook:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Plot
from bokeh.plotting import *
from bokeh.models.renderers import GlyphRenderer

outout_notebook()
source = make_source()  #ColumnDataSource type
plot = figure(title = 'test',
        tools = 'pan, wheel_zoom, select, reset',
        x_range = x_range,
        plot_width = 700, plot_height = 600)

colors = ['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow', 'pink', 'red', 'blue', 'orange', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow', 'pink']
colorcounter = 0

for x in symbols:
    if x!= ' ':
        plot.line(x = 'time', 
            y = x, 
            legend = x, 
            color = colors[colorcounter], 
            weight = '200px',
            source = source)
        colorcounter += 1

show()
renderer = [r for r in curplot().renderers if isinstance(r, GlyphRenderer)][0]
ds = renderer.data_source
```

At this point, the correct plot appears in my notebook.  To enable streaming, I then have:

```
while True:
    df = make_source()
    ds.data = df.data
    ds._dirty = True
    cursession().store_objects(ds)
    time.sleep(10)
```

but I keep getting the message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-d4967016d7d3> in <module>()
      3     ds.data = df.data
      4     ds._dirty = True
----> 5     cursession().store_objects(ds)
      6     time.sleep(10)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'store_objects'
```

Usually, this occurs when the object hasn't been "instantiated," but I don't understand how that would be the problem in this case. I have `bokeh-server` running in the background, in the same directory as my notebook. How can I instantiate the cursession(), so that I can stream in the notebook?  Do I have to output to server instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a URL to the bokeh server as an argument to `output_notebook` to cause a session to be created.